# Design of non-overlapping "1010" sequence detector

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequential-logic, sequence-detector

Assuming that **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** are the four states. When detecting the sequence "**1010**", in the **D** state, if overlapping is not allowed, we have the following state diagram:
[image: State diagram for "D" only]
[image: Complete state diagram]

After detecting "**1011**", why does the detector go back to **B** instead of having a self-loop to **D**? Wouldn't it become overlapping if we consider the "**1**" as the first bit of sequence "**1010**", because then the input sequence would be "101**1**010"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After detecting "1011", why does the detector go back to B

The diagram is correct for the non-overlapping sequence.  To get into state **D** requires the sequence **101**.  If the next input is **1** (resulting in the **1011** pattern), then the sequence is starting from the condition where you detected the 1st bit as **1**, as if you are in the **B** state.

To demonstrate that the diagram is correct, you can run this [Verilog simulation on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Zj2E).  It shows several example input data streams, but you can change the input sequence to whatever you want.

> Wouldn't it become overlapping

It would not be overlapping.  An example of overlapping is:

```
Input : 101010
Output: 000101
```